# My program is not returning true when I need it to in Python

Tags: python, function

I am creating a game and I have functions that takes parameters and returns a value. I want to check if the game has ended. The game endes when `bins = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. I have tried everything and cannot get gameIsOver to be true in the main function. What am I doing wrong?

```
bins = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

gameIsOver = False

def checkGameEnd(listOfBins):
    if listOfBins[0] == 0 and listOfBins[1] == 0 and listOfBins[2] == 0 and listOfBins[3] == 0 and listOfBins[4] == 0:
        gameDidEnd = True
        return True
    else:
        gameDidEnd = False
        return False

def _main_():
    print(displayGame(bins))
    checkGameEnd(bins)
    player_1 = "Player 1"
    player_2 = "Player 2"

    while didEndGame == False:
        turnPlayer1_bin = int(input(player_1 + ", which bin do you want to remove matches from?\t"))
        turnPlayer1_matches = int(input(player_1 + ", how many matches will you remove from bin " + str(turnPlayer1_bin) + "?\t"))
        removeMatches(turnPlayer1_bin, turnPlayer1_matches, bins)
        print(displayGame(bins))
        checkGameEnd(bins)
        if didEndGame == True:
            print(player_2 + ", you win!")


        turnPlayer2_bin = int(input(player_2 + ", which bin do you want to remove matches from?\t"))
        turnPlayer2_matches = int(input(player_2 + ", how many matches will you remove from bin " + str(turnPlayer2_bin) + "?\t"))
        removeMatches(turnPlayer2_bin, turnPlayer2_matches, bins)
        print(displayGame(bins))
        checkGameEnd(bins)
        if didEndGame == True:
            print(player_1 + ", you win!")

_main_()
```

Comment: Please post your code in a properly formatted way by talking advantage of the formatting facilities of the edit box. You might benefit from reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You aren't really asking a focused question so much as dumping buggy code on Stack Overflow and hoping that someone else will debug it for you.

Comment: You're not setting didEndGame.  You need `didEndGame = checkGameEnd(bins)`.  Also you can simplify checkGameEnd to `return listOfBins == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` as opposed to checking each element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `didEndGame` variable is not updating. You must assign it to the check function:

```
didEndGame = checkGameEnd(bins)
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkGameEnd(bins)` may return `True` but you're not assign it to `didEndGame`. And also you don't have to type `didEndGame == False` or `True`. Change your while loop with below code snippet:

```
while not didEndGame:
    turnPlayer1_bin = int(input(player_1 + ", which bin do you want to remove matches from?\t"))
    turnPlayer1_matches = int(input(player_1 + ", how many matches will you remove from bin " + str(turnPlayer1_bin) + "?\t"))
    removeMatches(turnPlayer1_bin, turnPlayer1_matches, bins)
    print(displayGame(bins))
    didEndGame = checkGameEnd(bins)
    if didEndGame:
        print(player_2 + ", you win!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrections of your code to create a working version

```
def checkGameEnd(bins): 
  return [0]*5 == bins  # check for bins is all zeros

def displayGame(bins):
  print('Bins:', *range(5))
  print('Vals:', *bins)

def removeMatches(turnPlayer1_bin, turnPlayer1_matches, bins):
  bins[turnPlayer1_bin] -= turnPlayer1_matches

def main(): 
  # Initialize bins
  bins = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]

  displayGame(bins)

  player_1 = "Player 1" 
  player_2 = "Player 2"

  while True:
      turnPlayer1_bin = int(input(player_1 + ", which bin do you want to remove matches from?\t"))
      turnPlayer1_matches = int(input(player_1 + ", how many matches will you remove from bin " + str(turnPlayer1_bin) + "?\t"))
      removeMatches(turnPlayer1_bin, turnPlayer1_matches, bins)

      displayGame(bins)

      if checkGameEnd(bins):
          print(player_2 + ", you win!")
          break

      turnPlayer2_bin = int(input(player_2 + ", which bin do you want to remove matches from?\t"))
      turnPlayer2_matches = int(input(player_2 + ", how many matches will you remove from bin " + str(turnPlayer2_bin) + "?\t"))
      removeMatches(turnPlayer2_bin, turnPlayer2_matches, bins)

      displayGame(bins)

      if checkGameEnd(bins):
          print(player_1 + ", you win!")
          break

main()
```